# TabBarView which in column in SingleChildScrollView needs to wrap in a specified height container

Tags: flutter

1. I have a page which contains a TabBar, some other widgets and a TabBarView releated to the above TabBar. The build implementation is like the following.

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(color: defaultBackgroundColor),
      child: Stack(children: [
        Image.asset(
          'assets/background/around.jpg',
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          height: 400,
          fit: BoxFit.fill,
        ),
        SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              AroundHeader(),
              TabBar(
                controller: _tabController,
                unselectedLabelColor: Colors.white,
                indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab,
                labelColor: Colors.blue,
                indicator: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.transparent,
                  border:
                      Border(bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue, width: 3)),
                ),
                tabs: [
                  ...data.map(
                    (item) => Tab(
                      child: Container(
                        child: Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          child: Text(item, style: titleStyle),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 10),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: commonMargin),
                child: Container(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height + 300,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 2 * commonMargin,
                  child: TabBarView(
                    controller: _tabController,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      AroundRecommend1(),
                      AroundRecommend2(),
                      AroundRecommend3(),
                      AroundRecommend4(),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ]),
    );
  }
```

2. Because the contents in TabBarView may variable height, AroundRecommend for example is build from a Column.
3. Now I have to manual calculate the maximum height of the height of children of TabBarView.
4. I tried to replace the constrained container with a `Explanded` or `SizedBox.expand` or `IntrinsicHeight` and so on, but all of them failed with exception like height is not provided.

Answer (score 1):

You want to wrap the widgets inside the column in `Expanded` not the `Column` itself

```
  Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          child: Container(
             height: 200,
            color: Colors.redAccent,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
```

Comment: This is not work. because I have some big height contents in TabBarView, and it introduce scroll behaviour, it is more like shrinkwrap or sliver behaviour.

Comment: So I guess I am confused if you could explain how expanded is acting like shrinkwrap?

Comment: are you still having this issue